# SQLServer 2005: Error converting date 'yyyy-mm-dd' in query

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

I have this condition in a query:

```
WHERE fielddate> = '2010-10-01 'AND fielddate <= '2010-10-18'
```

to migrate the database to another server (2008) with the same engine database (sqlserver-2005 Express), returned error:

> The conversion of a char data type to
>   a datetime data type resulting in an
>   out-of-range datetime value.

But if I make this query works

```
WHERE fielddate> = '20101001 'AND fielddate <= '20101018'
```

the collation type is the same:

> Modern_Spanish_CI_AS

and all the other features that I saw are the same.

I do not know what the problem is

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way these ambiguous date formats are interpreted depends upon the default language for the login. Presumably your login in one instance has a different language than in the other instance.

It is best practice to avoid these ambiguous formats.

Answer (score 1):

Check the locale of the server, but you can also use CONVERT and specify the date format :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: It is not the locale of the *server* directly. It is the locale of the *login*.

Answer (score -1):

The problem stems from the fact that your data is stored in a character field rather than a datetime field.  Especially since different collations will write / read differently into character fields.

**Make the Change**

My first suggestion would be to change the data type of the field to DateTime. Since you are going to a brand new SQL 2008 database, you may want to take advantage and change any dates stored in character formats to actual DateTime

**CAST and CONVERT**

You can use `CAST` to explicitly convert the field as in

```
WHERE 1=1
AND CAST (fielddate AS DATETIME) >= '2010-10-01 'AND 
CAST (fielddate AS DATETIME) <= '2010-10-18'
```

Comment: It is a string literal not a date stored in a char column. It will be implicitly cast to datetime anyway when used in a predicate against a datetime column which is why he sees the error message he is seeing.

Comment: the system is great and I can not change it all